# More efficient powerset algorithm haskell

Tags: haskell, powerset

I Have a powerset function which creates a list [[a]] but the largest [a] is worked out first, meaning the whole algorithm has to run before I can get the smaller values.

I need a function which returns a powerset, in ascending order, so I could take the first n values of the function and the whole algorithm would not need to run.

Current simple algorithm

```
powerset :: [a] -> [[a]]
powerset [] = [[]]
powerset (x:xs) = [x:ps | ps <- powerset xs] ++ powerset xs
```

Comment: Just reverse the order of arguments to `++`?

Comment: If you take the first *n* items, then if *n* is small, it does not require the whole algorithm to run in your current attempt.

Comment: @DanielWagner, that would make it *less* lazy, no?

Comment: @dfeuer The original question is incredibly ambiguous. My reading, after puzzling over it several times, was that the existing `powerset` outputs large sets first, and they wanted to output small sets first. I actually don't *know* what the correct interpretation is, but that's my best guess. To get a good solution that is sufficiently lazy, we first have to know what is wanted -- and we don't know that. So I proposed the smallest change I could think of that would move in the "correct direction".

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by ascending order, but consider this solution:

```
powerset' :: [a] -> [[a]]
powerset' = loop [[]]
  where
    loop :: [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
    loop acc [] = acc
    loop acc (x:xs) = loop (acc ++ fmap (\e -> e ++ [x]) acc) xs
```

We start with the powerset of the empty list, which is `[[]]`, and expand it for each new element we encounter in the input list. The expansion is by appending the new element in each sublist we already emitted.

It requires that we append elements to the sublists exponentially many times, so I also considered using `Data.DList` from the `dlist` package that provides an efficient `snoc` operator that appends new elements to the end of the list:

```
import Data.DList

powerset :: [a] -> [[a]]
powerset xs = toList <$> loop [empty] xs
  where
    loop :: [DList a] -> [a] -> [DList a]
    loop acc [] = acc
    loop acc (y:ys) = loop (acc ++ fmap (`snoc` y) acc) ys
```

In my (rough) experiments, though, the first solution uses way less memory in the REPL and thus finishes faster for bigger input lists.

In both cases, this is what you get at the end:

```
$> powerset [1,2,3]
[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]

$> powerset_original [1,2,3]
[[1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,2,3],[],[2],[3],[2,3]]
```